# What is the right equivalent of Eval("this")

Tags: asp.net

I have this ListView that displays a custom user control. 
The custom user control has a property MyObject.
When i databind the collection of MyObjects to the ListView, the only way to pass the MyObject to the custom user control that i can think of is to make the collection a `Dictionary<MyObject,string>` and to put the `Eval("Key")` in the markup.

My question is: how do i skip this dictionary step? Is there a equivalent of `Eval("this")`

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewSearchInputs" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>                        
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>        
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:SearchFieldInput runat="server" MyObject='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButtonAddFieldQuery" OnClick="ButtonAddFieldQueryClick" Text="Add New QueryField" >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Container.DataItem` which should give you the current item being data bound.

Comment: MyObject='<%# Container.DataItem %>'

Thank you.